# Does [windows-xp-sp3] need its own tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

There are 73 questions tagged [windows-xp-sp3](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp-sp3).

Does this version really need its own tag? I'm sure that questions related to specific service packs can be tagged [service-pack](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/service-pack). Also we wouldn't create [osx-10.6.8](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx-10.6.8) and [osx-10.6.7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx-10.6.7) and [osx-10.6.6](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx-10.6.6), etc.

What do you think? Merge into [windows-xp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp) or leave them be?

Comment: Most likely not

Comment: There are about as many major releases (10.x) of OS X as there are Windows releases and service packs in the same time. Comparing the dozens of minor updates to OS X just isn't appropriate.

Comment: @DanielBeck Sure, it's not a perfect comparison, but in essence, it's the same *kind* of update, mostly not introducing lots of new features, still a new version, etc.

Comment: SP3 is hardly a minor update, and let's not start about the KBs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the 2 meta answers, [windows-xp-sp3](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp-sp3) has been merged into [windows-xp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp)

Answer (score 4):

While the service pack someone is on can be important in XP, it being a seperate tag is not.

The [Windows-XP] tag alone can identify the windows XP operating system for the purposes of tags.

Comment: I know you like to say a little more, but I think it would be beneficial to the discussion if you could just summarize your post to the bare minimum *related to the current issue*. The rest, well, A) if you don't mess with tags, why do you care? :) B) you don't have to be a mod to do most things with tags.

Comment: It is written.  I will put it in its own thread.

Answer (score 3):

Well to be honest, most problems are not specific to the service pack. They're mostly just problems about [windows-xp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp). I don't think there's a huge need for it. If it is needed to make a point, its mentioned in the question.

As Daniel said in the comments, it would be like adding on another tag for every OS X update.